# No data appearing in ListView, using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

With the below code, nothing appears in the `ListActivity` as I would expect.
No errors are shown in logcat.

**Arrival.java**

```
package one.two;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Arrival extends ListActivity
{
    private ListView listView;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ArrayList<String> retList = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Start onCreate Function\n");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println("In onCreate Function\n");
        System.out.println("In of GetData\n");
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 

        System.out.println("DB Open\n");
        db.open();
        System.out.println("DB Opened\n");
        retList = getData();
        System.out.println("Out of GetData\n");
        // force count no. of records in table
        // dump to check index
        int cnt = 2;

        int i=0;
        for (i = 0; i<cnt; i++)
            System.out.println(retList.toString());
        System.out.println("Array 2 String\n");

        Cursor c = db.getCursor();
        String[] from = new String[] {DBAdapter.status};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.txt1};


        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listtext, c, from, to);
        this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        System.out.println("Show List\n");
        db.close();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getData()
     {


        ArrayList<String> items = DBAdapter.getAllTitles();
        System.out.println("Return a LIST titles\n");
         return items;
        }


    }
```

**DBAdapter.java**

```
package one.two;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBAdapter
{
    public static String status = "status";
    public String id = "id";
    public String arrival = "arrival";
    public String destination = "destination";
    public String ferry = "ferry";
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/one.two/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ferry.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "port";
    public static Context context;
    public Cursor c;

    public static SQLiteDatabase DbLib;

        //overloaded non-null constructor
    public DBAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        DbLib = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,  SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
        System.out.println("OpenOrCreateDB Done");
    }

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        Context context;
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;

        }//end constructor DatabaseHelper

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                int newVersion)
        {
        }//end onUpgrade()

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
        }//end onCreate()
    }// end class DatabaseHelper

    private static DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    //private static SQLiteDatabase DbLib;

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


        public static ArrayList<String> getAllTitles()
        {

            ArrayList<String> port = new ArrayList<String>();
                Cursor c=null;


                c = DbLib.query("port",
                        new String[] { "status", "id", "arrival",
                                "destination", "ferry" }, null, null,
                        null, null, null);
                try {
                    if (c!=null) { // start - when there is at least 1 record
                        System.out.println("Cursor is NOT NULL");

                        int i =0;
                        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) 

                        {
                                    // Debug Stm
                            System.out.println("Record No. "+i);
                            System.out.println(c.getString(0));
                            System.out.println(c.getString(1));
                            System.out.println(c.getString(2));
                            System.out.println(c.getString(3));
                            System.out.println(c.getString(4));
                            // Assign database cursor.records to arraylist
                            port.add(i,c.getString(0));
                            port.add(i,c.getString(1));
                            port.add(i,c.getString(2));
                            port.add(i,c.getString(3));
                            port.add(i,c.getString(4));
                            i = i + 1;

                        }
                    } // end - where there is at least 1 record


                } finally {
                    if (c!=null) {
                    c.close();
                }

                }   
            return port;
        }//end getAllTitles()

        public void open() {
            //Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            DbLib = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }
        public Cursor getCursor(){
            return c;

        }

        public void close()
        {
            DbLib.close();

        }

    }//end class DBAdapter
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- snip... -->
<ListView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_y="132dip"
    android:layout_x="150dip"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick guess, I'd say it's because you're closing the database connection in your `onCreate` method, before the list adapter has a chance to read any data from it.  The `Cursor` itself doesn't contain all the data as soon as you run a query.

If you want your `Activity` to handle closing the database connection, you should do so in the `onPause` or `onDestroy` method.

Comment: So i would have to put db.close() in another onDestroy method for my Arrival.java?

Comment: You would move it from `onCreate()` to `onDestroy()`, as then it matches the `Activity` lifecycle: the DB is opened when the `Activity` is created, and closed when it's destroyed (i.e. the adapter no longer needs data access).

Comment: I edited the code to
  public void onDestroy()
 {
  DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 
    db.close();
 }
There is still no data shown in my listview.

Comment: No, you're closing a *new* instance of the `DBAdapter`. Move the `db` variable in `onCreate()` to a field so that it's accessible from `onDestroy`.

Comment: Also, you could check at `onCreate` whether the `Cursor` you're getting back actually contains the data you expect, if you're not calling `db.close()` from `onCreate` any more.